# Error in service

Tags: android

i got this code and it shoes an error
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type UpdateService must implement the inherited abstract method 
     Service.onBind(Intent)
    - Illegal modifier for the class UpdateService; only public, abstract & final are permitted

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

public static class UpdateService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new Receiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
    if (!screenOn) {
        // your code
    } else {
        // your code
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please read the error, it is very simple, it saying you have to override the `onBind` method.

Comment: may i ask how to override the onBind method please give me the code

Comment: See this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html you will find there !